# Chrome extension -- periodically update files from remote server

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension where I need to load some data from a json file. I am hoping to store this json file on Github, and from my extension load this json file (so that any changes on the json file will be reflected on the extension). However, it is inefficient to always load from the remote server, so I am thinking if I could make the extension download the json file periodically (for eg once every month), and read the data from the local json file?

I notice that there is a chrome.downloads.download api. But how to I make it download periodically, and where are the files (ie how do I get the file path) stored after downloaded?

Comment: No, you should simply use `fetch` and store the result in `chrome.storage.local` (as an object) or in `localStorage` (as a string). For scheduling you can use vanilla JS checks via Date.now() or `chrome.alarms` API.

Comment: Thanks for your help. From my content script, I tried fetching the json file using `$.getJson(<github_url>)` , but it has a CORS policy error. How is it possible enable permission to fetch from Github. In my manifest.json, I've already given permission to all website
` "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "storage",
   "http://*/*",
          "https://*/*"
 ],
`

Comment: Do it in the background script.

Comment: Thanks, it works. For `chrome.alarms` api, does the time continue to count even when i close my browser?

Comment: Yes it counts but now I remember it's bugged: if the scheduled alarm hits while the browser isn't running, the alarm won't fire next time the browser starts, which can happen with the next alarm and the next one so you'll never see it if the interval is big. It's probably best to use a different approach e.g. Date.now() checks inside some other `chrome` events.